# How to display images that was uploaded in the media gallery and not by the current post?

Tags: gallery

I have uploaded images before in my other posts and now I want to display it in my Photo Gallery. I'm using an isotope layout so I'm not using the native gallery of WordPress. It's working just fine however I can't display the images that is not uploaded directly to that post. For example the images that I've uploaded before. If I upload a new one to this current post, then that will display.

Here's my code:

```
        // DISPLAY ALL IMAGES FROM A PARENT GALLERY
        $attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => $post->ID,
          'post_status' => 'inherit',
          'post_type' => 'attachment',
          'post_mime_type' => 'image',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));
        foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
```

So how can I display those past images in my gallery?

Comment: Please clarify what images you want to retrieve. What do you mean by "images that I've uploaded before" and "past images in my gallery"?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `'post_parent' => $post->ID` to `'post_parent' => null` will fetch all images.

Comment: It is not clear the OP wants "all images". There seems to be a condition for images in a "parent gallery" or "past images in my gallery".

Comment: I see...`I have uploaded images before in my other posts` could mean, that he want's to get images which have been attached to any post in the past only without images, which are not attached to a post. I edit my answer as soon as we get more information.

Comment: I don't think you are wrong, necessarily, but the question isn't clear.